# Prompting user to select their scanner app from a mobile browser

Tags: java, android, iphone

Is there a browser variant of android intents?

My goal is for this link on a **mobile browser**:

```
 <a href="scan://scan/" data-scheme="scan://scan/" >Take me to a scanner!</a>
```

to tell the device to bring up the generic "choose a scanner app to continue" prompt rather than a specific one. i.e. `zxing://scan/`   or `scan://scan/`

Is there generic protocol I can use in the `<a href=""></a>` where the device looks at all registered scanners?

Edit: Sorry I wasn't clear, I'm going from browser -> mobile app. So all I have is javascript to help me and no access to native code

Comment: I don't think that there is a generic "scan" app / uri schema.

Comment: Bummer, thanks anyways fellas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No you must use Android's intents (or react-native Linking)